# Issue reading and downloading PDF using NextJS13 api route doesnt seem to read the pdf and just outputs error

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, next.js13

Cannot seem to get the PDF file to a downloadable state. fileStream doesnt seem to read the file with output of 0 bytes read and if I am correct I shouldnt be passing a response as the fileStream is the response or maybe I need to pass that into the NextResponse or something along those lines? I am fairly certain my path is correct to the file I have quadruple checked. I am using the absolute path as well /home/MYUSER/pdfs/test.pdf

My route file resides in my next project at /home/MYUSER/next/app/api/pdf/route.ts and trying it by visiting the url localhost:3000/api/pdf

My current code is producing this error "Error: No response is returned from route handler '/home/MYUSER/next/app/api/pdf/route.ts'. Ensure you return a `Response` or a `NextResponse` in all branches of your handler."

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        const pdfPath = resolve('/home/MYUSER/pdfs/test.pdf')

        // Set headers
        const headers = new Headers()
        headers.append('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf')
        headers.append('Content-type', 'application/pdf')

        const fileStream = createReadStream(pdfPath)

        fileStream.on('open', () => {
            // Pipe the file stream to the response
            fileStream.pipe(res)
        })

        fileStream.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error(error)
            res.status(500).end('Internal Server Error')
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(500).end('Internal Server Error')
    }
}
```

Have been searching around and I have been staring at this for awhile and was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction.